# Emacs / Elisp / Closure / Toggle

Tags: emacs, closures, elisp

I currently have the following:

```
(defun my-hide-code ()                                                                                                                         
  (interactive)                                                                                                                                
  (set-selective-display 2))                                                                                                                   

(defvar my-keys-minor-mode-map (make-keymap) "my-keys-minor-mode keymap.")                                                                     
(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "<f2>") 'my-hide-code)                                                                                 
(define-minor-mode my-keys-minor-mode                                                                                                          
  "use"                                                                                                                                        
  t " my-keys" 'my-keys-minor-mode-map)                                                                                                        
(my-keys-minor-mode 1)
```

Now, I want  to toggle between
(set-selective-display 2)
and
(set-selective-display 'nil)

Now, if I was in scheme, I would just create a s closure, and the closure would store a state variable, which would allow me to know which state I was in, and how to toggle.

However, Elisp is apparently a lisp-2 where variables and functions have different scope. Given this, how do I create closures / have  be a toggle key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selective-display` itself is the variable that contains the state you need to check, so you can write

```
(defun my-toggle-selective-display ()
  (interactive)
  (if selective-display
      (set-selective-display nil)
    (set-selective-display 2)))
```

As for closures in general, I had need of them for a project long ago and resorted to inserting uninterned symbols into a function definition using backquote substitution to avoid global variables.  E.g.

```
(fset 'toggler
      (let ((toggle-var (make-symbol "toggle")))
        (set toggle-var nil)
        `(lambda () (interactive)
           (cond (,toggle-var
                  (setq ,toggle-var nil))
                 (t
                  (setq ,toggle-var t)))
           (message "toggle is %s" ,toggle-var))))
```

which when run produces

```
M-x toggler
toggle is t
M-x toggler
toggle is nil
M-x toggler
toggle is t
M-: (boundp 'toggle)
nil
```

I guess this qualifies as a kludge, but I know of no other way to get anything like a closure in Emacs-Lisp.

Comment: Upvoted & accepted. Out of curiosity, is there  generic solution in elisp (w/o defining global vars all over the place?) In scheme, I would do something like (let [state ...] (lambda () ...))

Comment: There are also the long-standard `lexical-let` and `lexical-let*` macros, which automate some of the kludginess.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs 24 supports lexical binding, so real closures can be written.

See:
[What are the new rules for variable scoping in Emacs 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654848/what-are-the-new-rules-for-variable-scoping-in-emacs-24)

Just be aware that dynamic binding is a *very* large part of what makes Emacs so customizable, so use lexical binding with due care if you are writing something which may be of use to others -- ensure that you `defvar` any variable which *might* potentially be useful for someone to override (ensuring, of course, that you think up all those potential use-cases that don't apply to you! :)

For Emacs < 24, see:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FakeClosures
- [Other Stack Overflow Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[emacs]+FakeClosures)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to an answer I gave elsewhere about how to create real (not fake)
closures in Elisp:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14088107/1857114

I use a macro I call **defun****.  It works in Emacs 24.2.1 but I'm not sure what
earlier versions it works for.  Presumably the **defun** special form will be
upgraded some time in the future and the macro will be unnecessary.